# pyplot, why isn't the x-axis showing?

Tags: python, plot

I'm trying to plot some values against date. However, unfortunately i'm not getting any values in the x Axis. I feel that this could be due to two factors:

1. The values are stored as "dates" so that is complicating the procedure
2. Since the date will occupy too much real estate on the x axis its getting too cluttered and hence that's why I only see a black line.

Please, let me know how I can improve this so that I'm able to get the major ticks that are appropriately spaced out.

My current code is:

```
fig1 = plt.plot(Sleep['dateOfSleep'], Sleep['TotalDeepSleep'])
plt.show()
plt.clf
```

the output that I get is:

[image: Output]

Comment: Can you provide some of your code? And you get no entries on the x-axis but the plot itself appears? Could you post a picture how your plot looks like?

Comment: Sorry. Just did. My bad.

Comment: how about `plt.autofmt_xdate()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control the major and minor ticks locations and formats you will need to use [date tickers](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/dates_api.html#date-tickers).  Here is a function I regularly use for plot time series that span multiple months:

```
def format_xaxis(fig):
     # here I am setting the major ticks to each decade
     # Change to something appropriate for your data
     major= dates.MonthLocator(bymonthday=1)

     #Here I am setting each minor ticks to mid-decade 
     # Change to something appropriate for your data    
     minor=dates.MonthLocator(bymonthday=15)

     #Here I am setting each major ticks and minor tick formatting
     # Change to something appropriate for your data 
     #look at http://strftime.org/ for other options
     majorfmt = dates.DateFormatter('%B')
     minorfmt = dates.DateFormatter('%d')

     # Set the locators and formats for all of the subplots axes
     [i.xaxis.set_major_locator(major) for i in fig.axes]
     [i.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minor) for i in fig.axes]
     [i.xaxis.set_major_formatter(majorfmt) for i in fig.axes]
     [i.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(minorfmt) for i in fig.axes]

     # Here I am offsetting the major ticks down so they dont overlap with minor tick lables
     [i.get_xaxis().set_tick_params(which='major', pad=15) for i in fig.axes]

     #make them look nice
     for t in fig.axes:
         for tick in t.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
             tick.label1.set_horizontalalignment('center')
         for label in t.get_xmajorticklabels() :
             label.set_rotation(0)
             label.set_weight('bold')
         for label in t.xaxis.get_minorticklabels():
             label.set_fontsize('small')
```

You can swap out `dates.MonthLocator` for any locator appropriate for your data. Just look at the link I provided.

A little example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range(start = '2015-01-01', end = '2015-05-01'), 'TotalDeepSleep':np.random.randint(0,140,size=121)})


fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(df['Date'], df['TotalDeepSleep'])

format_xaxis(fig)
```

[image]